# Error while installing Oracle 11g in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, installation, ubuntu

**Also getting a runfixup.sh script which is also giving error**

[image: Prerequisite checks]
[image: Asking to run this script to fix prerequisite errors]

```
root@szh-server:/tmp/CVU_11.2.0.1.0_zuman# ./runfixup.sh 
Response file being used is :./fixup.response
Enable file being used is :./fixup.enable
Log file location: ./orarun.log
./orarun.sh: 186: [: true: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 848: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 864: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 882: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 903: [: true: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1052: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1057: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1075: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1085: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1115: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1143: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1189: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 139: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 139: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1228: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1284: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1342: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1426: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1451: [: unexpected operator
```

I'm getting the error from the script which is supposed to fix the installation errors. -_-

Any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, use a supported Linux distribution, like Oracle Linux, RHEL or SLES. For the full list: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/pre_install.htm#CHDFFBIF

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Oracle provided fixup scripts, I got the answer. The main script is orarun.sh which runs on bash.
So the following command does the trick!
PS: Remember, you need to be login as root.

```
bash ./orarun.sh fixup.response fixup.enable .
```